# Continuously create div's

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create `div` continuously and it should come on the next line if it reaches the outer `div`'s width in JavaScript without using `canvas` and `float`.

```
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var ind = (Math.round(Math.random(0,2)*2));
    var child = document.createElement("div");
    child.setAttribute("id","div"+i);
    child.style.backgroundColor=colors[ind];
    maindiv.appendChild(child);
}
```

Comment: Without `float` ? Why so ?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `display: inline-block;` css property. Refer [this](https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/)

```js
var maindiv = document.getElementById('parent');
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var ind = (Math.round(Math.random(0, 2) * 2));
  var child = document.createElement("div");
  child.setAttribute("id", "div" + i);
  child.setAttribute("class", "inline");
  child.innerText = 'div';
  //child.style.backgroundColor = colors[ind];
  maindiv.appendChild(child);
}
```

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```